# Proxy Pass for AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-application-load-balancer, proxypass

I have an EC2 Instance with NGINX installed and a simple config like so:

```
server_name server_1.domain.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass https://api.domain.cloud:8200/;
}
```

When I do a GET request to *http://server_1.domain.com/some/path* I get forwarded correctly to api.domain.cloud:8200 but it masks the domain as https://server_1.domain.com/some/path and the world makes sense.

How can I setup an AWS ALB in a similar way? I really don't wanna manage an EC2 Instance when I can just use an ALB/NLB. When I try to set this up in AWS ALB it does NOT mask the domain but instead tries to fwd to the http://api.domain.cloud:8200 and this URL is only able to resolve internally in AWS

This is my config for the ALB:

[image]

Is this even possible? This cannot be a simple web url rewrite because client needs a response from the API Server. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After much exploring I found out that this is not possible. The solution was to put an API Gateway in front of an Network Load Balancer. The API Gateway acts as a Proxy and resolved the issue for me. Happy to share my solution with anyone who is interested in the same.

Comment: can you share details about your solution? I'm trying to do the same but I cannot find any examples.